# Python 2.7 - Sum value on duplicates in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
list1=[{'a':'apples', 'b':'snack','count':2},{'a':'apples','b':'lunch','count':3},{'a':'apples','b':'snack','count':3}]
```

I need to group duplicates in the list on 'a' and 'b' and sum their 'count' such that:

```
list2=[{'a':'apples','b':'snack','count':5},{'a':'apples','b':'lunch','count':3}]
```

Searched through the repository here and haven't recognized a solution. Thanks very much for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` with a 2tuple to accumulate the counts, then push it back to a list...

```
list1=[{'a':'apples', 'b':'snack','count':2},{'a':'apples','b':'lunch','count':3},{'a':'apples','b':'snack','count':3}]

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(int)
for d in list1:
    dd[d['a'], d['b']] += d['count']

list2 = [{'a': k[0], 'b': k[1], 'count': v} for k, v in dd.iteritems()]

[{'a': 'apples', 'count': 3, 'b': 'lunch'}, {'a': 'apples', 'count': 5, 'b': 'snack'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using groupby and list,dict and generator comprehensions:

```
list1=[{'a':'apples', 'b':'snack','count':2},{'a':'apples','b':'lunch','count':3},{'a':'apples','b':'snack','count':3}]

from itertools import groupby
list1.sort()
group_func = lambda x: {key:val for key, val in x.iteritems() if key!='count'}
list2 = [dict(k, count = sum(item['count'] for item in items)) for k, items in groupby(list1, group_func)]

[{'a': 'apples', 'count': 3, 'b': 'lunch'}, {'a': 'apples', 'count': 5, 'b': 'snack'}]
```

Explanation:

- The grouper function takes an item and return a sub-dictionary
  without the 'count' item using dict-comprehension.
- Then groupby gathers all original list items with the same subdict
- Finally the list comprehension iterates those groups and sums (now using generator comprehension) the count items.

Cons:

- Less readable.
- For groupby to work it needs to be sorted, so that could make things slower.

Pros:

- If list1 is already sorted this is probably faster. (since comprehensions are generally faster in python)
- Shorter. (can even be written in a single barely comprehensible line :))