# Robot Framework: Merge and sum values of dictionaries with matching items in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, robotframework

After **scraping** a web table, I stored all the values for each row as a dictionary and then appending all the dictionaries in a list. In doing so, I get below dictionaries (sample) which can have the same key-value pairs, Eg: `store` `123` & `789` are present in 2 dictionaries:

```
${data} = [{store: 123, prov: 'ON' value: 10},{store: 456, prov: 'AB' value: 5},{store: 123, prov: 'ON' value: 4},{store: 789, prov: 'MB' value: 3},{store: 789, prov: 'MB' value: 7}]
```

How can i merge and sum `value` of all these dictionary items in order to get only unique elements like:

```
${data} = [{store: 123, prov: 'ON' value: 14},{store: 456, prov: 'AB' value: 5},{store: 789, prov: 'MB' value: 10}]
```

The solution can be provided using python as well.

**Note**: I found some python solutions but they only work when each dictionary is stored as a separate variable
[Merge and sum of two dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461531/merge-and-sum-of-two-dictionaries)

Comment: Answers in this post should help you out:   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102618/sum-values-in-a-list-of-lists-of-dictionaries-using-common-key-value-pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102618/sum-values-in-a-list-of-lists-of-dictionaries-using-common-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum values in a list of lists of dictionaries using common key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102618/sum-values-in-a-list-of-lists-of-dictionaries-using-common-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you don't want to store in a new dictionary and print like this?

```
data = [{'store': 123, 'value': 10},{'store': 456, 'value': 5},{'store': 123, 'value': 
4},{'store': 789, 'value': 3},{'store': 789, 'value': 7}]

Dict = {}
for x in data:
        if x['store'] in Dict:
                Dict[x['store']] += x['value']
        else:
                Dict[x['store']] = x['value']
     
print([{'store':x,'value':y} for x,y in Dict.items()])
```

Comment: Thanks @osamu-zenji for the answer. I have slightly modified the `data`  values and added extra key-value pair `prov` which i forgot to mention earlier.  I would like to store the data in a new list of dictionaries instead of the solution provided by you. **Note**: if there are matching stores, only the `value` will change, other key-values pairs will remain same.